# Incorrect syntax error using sp_MSforeachtable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I plan to get all tables with their total row count in  sql server 2000.

For which I did :

```
sp_msforeachtable 'select count(*) from ?'
```

In this column header is not mentioned, because of which its not distinguishable to which row count belongs to which table

For which I altered this by :

```
sp_msforeachtable 'select count(*) as ? from ?'
```

But its throwing an error as :

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Could you please guide on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    sysobjects.Name, sysindexes.Rows
FROM
    sysobjects
    INNER JOIN sysindexes
    ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
WHERE
    type = 'U'
    AND sysindexes.IndId < 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sysindexes.IndId < 2" & why?

Comment: Only for Heap and clustered Indexes

Comment: Will that include all the tables? Tables which will not have any indexes not even primary key?

Comment: Yes they will be included too

Comment: Many Thanks but I'm scared it would not provide real time data, as it much faster then sp_MSforeachtable. Any ideas Why so?

Comment: Looks like it isn't realtime, but could be made to be so: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/sysindexes-table.13767/ not sure how this would affect performance though!

Comment: I dont think this provides realtime data.

Comment: @Darkzaelus guess its the solution, DBCC UPDATEUSAGE with count rows seems to work according to the link you provided.

Comment: I wonder what the performance is like? Does `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` update all table counts? If so, not sure I would want to do that in realtime!

Comment: @Pratik do you actually need real-time results? Could you not just provide a fairly accurate estimate? Index row counts seem to get recounted fairly often by themselves.

Comment: Well not really but what difference can i expect in fairly accurate estimate & actual one's? Would that be just negligible or ranging in some percentage?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used it. I'd probably just do a little test to see how often it gets updated. Maybe insert a record a second and see how often the row count updates

Comment: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/how-to-determine-when-index-statistics-need-updating.28427/ Might be an interesting read

Answer (score 3):

I guess I got it :

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select count(*) as nr_of_rows, ''?'' 
  as table_name from ?'
```

Comment: It helped me to update statistics of all tables in one shot as:     EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'Update Statistics ? with FULLSCAN';

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
sp_MSforeachtable 'select ''?'' Tablename, count(*) ''Rows'' from ?'
```